# SQL select rows if contains any keys but not all of keys are null

Tags: sql

I have table like this

```
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| row  | a     | b     | c     |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1    | 1     |       | 1     |
| 2    | 2     |       | 2     |
| 3    |       | 3     | 3     |
| 4    |       | 4     | 4     |
| 5    | null  | null  | null  |
+------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to get rid row 5, my logic so far is `where not (a is null and b is null and c is null)` but it does not remove row 5. if I do `where (a is not null and b is not null and c is not null)` it will remove all the rows. I've tried all the possible combination of and & or that crossed in my mind but still cannot get what I try to achieve. Can someone help me?

Comment: where a is not null or b is not null etc

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Comment: Your query works perfect here https://sqlize.online/sql/psql11/c2f4b95754a869f2d60b349ba8ea00b9/

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT yt.*
FROM your_table yt
WHERE COALESCE(a,b,c) is not null ;
```

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qce_g1LP)

The coalesce can be used to return first not null value. If there are multiple columns, and all columns have NULL value then it returns NULL otherwise it will return first not null value.

Comment: `COALESCE()` is SQL standard, and supported by most DBMS:es.

Comment: This must be the same as `where not (a is null and b is null and c is null)` which he says does not work. (for some reason)